# Is lung size/shape a factor in long-continuous running of animals?

Tags: physiology, zoology, anatomy, lungs

Apart from other factors, does lung shape/structure/size play any role in long-continuous running animals.

Is there any similarity in lung structure between different long-continuous running species?